# check in specific date format if not add 0 at end java

Tags: java, date-format

I am trying to check the date is in required format and if its not in required format(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss) i need to add zero at the end to return a date in required format
For example if i get String inputDate= 2018-08-04T09:07:12.42 and i need to convert inputdate to 2018-08-04T09:07:12.420.
For convertStringToDate i am passing inputDate = 2018-08-04T09:07:12.42 and dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS". I tried the below code, but im not sure where i am missing . Pls suggest

```
 public Date convertStringToDate(String inputDate, String dateFormat) {
    String formattedInput = inputDate;
    try {
      // add milliseconds if missing from date
      if (validateDateFormat(inputDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") && !validateDateFormat(inputDate, dateFormat)) {
        formattedInput = inputDate + "0";
      }
      Log.logInfo(this, "formattedInput: " + formattedInput);
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
      return simpleDateFormat.parse(formattedInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.logError(this, "error in inputDate: " + formattedInput + " - convertStringToDate: " + e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
  }

 public boolean validateDateFormat(String strDate, String dateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
    Date javaDate = null;
    try {
      javaDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
      Log.logInfo(this, "formattedInput Date: " + javaDate);
      return true;
    }
    /* Date format is invalid */
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.logInfo(this, strDate + " is Invalid Date format");
      return false;
    }
    /* Return true if date format is valid */
  }
```

Comment: hmm, i do curious why did you have the need to "verify" it to be the `..HH:mm:sss` format then "fix it up" before parsing it with the other format. isn't if it works with the hardcoded format you can immediately return a `Date`? also, i'm not quite sure what do you meant by *"I tried the below code, but im not sure where i am missing."* does the output broke? got error messages?

Comment: How can you be sure that altered `String` matches the format provided as an argument?

Comment: Besides that, `Date` class is obsolete since Java 8.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()` parses your string without any explicit formatter and no matter if there are 1, 2 or 3 decimals after the decimal point. Exploit that and do away with `SimpleDateFormat`. See if you can do away with `Date` too. If you can’t, convert using something like `Date.from(parsedLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())`.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Parse your date-time strings using [`LocalDateTime#parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH)` to format the obtained `LocalDateTime`.

### Details

Irrespective of whether you have one/two/three digits in the *fraction-of-second* part of your date-time strings, they are compliant with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards and therefore, you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your date-time strings into a `LocalDateTime` by using [`LocalDateTime#parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

However, to keep three digits always in the string resulting from formatting the `LocalDateTime`, you need to use `.SSS` with the formatter i.e. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                "2018-08-04T09:07:12.421",
                "2018-08-04T09:07:12.42",
                "2018-08-04T09:07:12.4"
            )
            .map(LocalDateTime::parse)
            .map(dt -> dt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH)))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2018-08-04T09:07:12.421
2018-08-04T09:07:12.420
2018-08-04T09:07:12.400
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note**: In March 2014, `java.time` API supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it has been strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.